# Android sensors reception to sockets

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have been unable to manipulate a problem of receiving a data from sensors and send them via a socket in its own thread without loosing a data.

I have an Android service that needs to receive data from sensors. I want to open a TCP socket that connects to a PC to send the gathered data. My problem is that receiving data is fater than the socket task, it is unable to send all data gathered by sensors, since the socket service is doing things with interface.

Please any idea where I may find an example of a socket in synchronization with the reception of data?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Using an iOS device to control a game on your browser](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2012/using-an-ios-device-to-control-a-game-on-your-browser/)

Since they are using standard [html5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/) I think it is possible to implement the same in andorid.
Plus [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) are great.